# assigning type to a variable and using it to initialize other objects

Tags: c#

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
tybeVariable = Double;
typeVariable newDoubleVariable = 5;
```

I want to define a variable which will contain a type itself and then to initialize objects with it.

Comment: _assigning type to a variable_ No afaik.

Comment: no its not possible but you can use `dynamic` than can be any type.the type of `dynamic` is resolved at runtime. same thing as you want

Comment: You could use reflection(`Sytem.Type`) to juggle with the types, but there is no `typedef` like in C or C++

Answer (score -3):

You can use **var** keyword. Its implicitly type keyword. You can read more about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb383973.aspx)

Comment: That is not related to this question.

Comment: `var` infers the type this has nothing to do with the question